# program reports that ports 81 and 82 are opened

Tags: c#

When I check port for specific host it reports that ports 81 & 82 are opened.
But when I used online checkers they reported that ports 81 & 82 are closed. 
What's the problem?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string host = "google.com";
        for (int port = 79; port < 83; port++)
        {
            IPAddress ipadr = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)[0];

            try
            {
                Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                            SocketType.Stream,
                                            ProtocolType.Tcp);
                sock.Connect(ipadr, port);
                if (sock.Connected)
                    Console.WriteLine("Port {0} is opened", port);
                sock.Close();

                //return;
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Port {0} is closed", port);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

But for example it reports that port 79 is closed.
What's the problem?

Comment: You did know that testing anything against google.com is a great way to have them block you?  I've seen them turn off all services to particular IP addresses based on things like this.

Comment: For `microsoft.com` the same ports 81 & 82 are opened too

Comment: Use telnet and try to open it.  See what happens.

Comment: No.  I mean go to a cmd prompt.  Type "telnet google.com 81"  If the window locks up for awhile that means the port is closed.  If it responds back with blank area or with some type of banner then it's open.  If you don't have telnet installed (it's not by default) google how to install telnet for your OS.

Comment: Do these online checkers check if *your* ports are closed or do they check Google's?

Comment: BTW, when I run that code, those ports are closed on google and MS.

Comment: telnet returns nothing. i mean - when i `telnet google.com 81` - black screen(blank area). When I `telnet google.com 79` - it the same window with `connecting to google.com....._`(translated from russian)